# python reporting tool, similar to birtviewer

Tags: python, reporting

Can you guys please tell if building my own birtviewer like reporting tool but using python is a crazy idea. The company I'm working now, we are using birtviewer to generate reports for the clients, but I'm already getting frustrated tweaking the code to suit our client needs and it's written on massive java code which I don't have any experience at all. And they don't want to mavenize birtviewer, so every new releases I have to manually update my local copy and mavenize it. And the fact that it is really owned by a private company worries me about the future of birtviewer. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Write it. Make it open source and give us a git repo to have a little look... Honestly if the problem exists solve it.